# How to find all web-elements on which has text in them & sort them according to their position?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, position, point

I want to find all web elements that are visible on a page- like text, images, links etc and then arrange them according to their position i.e. from top-left to bottom-right

**EDIT**

How can i find all the  web elements which have text in them?
Using:

List allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*/text()"));

is giving this exception - org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.

Comment: Create an xpath to get the element tags you desire. Or if you are using annotations use @FindAll(java code others look it up) and including the tags you want with @FindBy tagname clause. You will get the elements in a list. I think it should be sorted as you want, else you can custom sort using the getLocation() which returns top left coordinates

Comment: How can I sort using getLocation()? Can you explain in brief.

Comment: getLocation() returns a Point object with x and y co-ordinates. Compare values based on these variables. Google sorting in the programming language...